# Get part of the current url PHP

Tags: php, geturl

How i cant get a specific part of the current url? for example, my current url is:

`http://something.com/index.php?path=/something1/something2/something3/`

Well, i need to print `something2` with php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `explode` function in PHP to separate the URL by the first parameter (in this case a forward slash). To achieve your goal you could use;

```
$url = "http://something.com/index.php?path=/something1/something2/something3/";
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$value = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```

Comment: It is not `Explode`, it is `explode`

Comment: My bad, accidental capitalisation.

Answer (score 3):

All these other example seem to focus on your exact example.  My guess is that you need a more flexible way of doing this, as the explode-only approach is very fragile if your URL changes and you still need to get data out of `path` parameter in query string.

I will point out the `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` functions to you.

```
// your URL string
$url = 'http://something.com/index.php?path=/something1/something2/something3/';

// get the query string (which holds your data)
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// load the parameters in the query string into an array
$param_array = array();
parse_str($query_string, $param_array);

// now you can look in the array to deal with whatever parameter you find useful. In this case 'path'

$path = $param_array['path'];

// now $path holds something like '/something1/something2/something3/'
// you can use explode or whatever else you like to get at this value.
$path_parts = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));

// see the value you are interested in
var_dump($path_parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$url = explode('/', 'http://something.com/index.php?path=/something1/something2/something3/');
echo $url[5];
```