# getting part of current page url in php

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a url something like this:

```
http://example.com/a/b/c.php
```

If I do a `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, I get `example.com`

If I do a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, I get `a/b/c.php`

But I want output as `example.com/a/` I am assuming I will have to use some regex, not exactly sure how.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you :)

Comment: Just combine `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you will get url

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate, of like... 10% of the site? haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get part of the current url PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259219/get-part-of-the-current-url-php)

Comment: @mayersdesign yea you are possibly right, wonder how come I didn't get to that first before posting here

Comment: @Anusha if any of the below answer helped you with this, consider marking it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `explode`:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: @SagarV  Do you see what the OP just posted? "this seems to work :) thanks! "

Answer (score 2):

Or In regex way, you may do it like this:

```
^http(?:s)?:\/\/\K([^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/).*$
```

Demo

**Sample Source** ([Run Here](http://ideone.com/NXvI2y))

```
$re = '/^http(?:s)?:\/\/\K([^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/).*$/m';
$str = 'http://example.com/a/b/c.php';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```